# SQL adding a date range help please

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm using

```sql
  Select Customer.QuoteID, Quote.QuoteID
    From Customer, Quote
   Where Customer.QuoteID=Quote.QuoteID
Order By Quote.QuoteID
```

I'd like to then specify a date range (Quote.CreationDate) or at least show dates greater than 31/03/2013, but I am not sure how to add this?

I am hoping to use a dialog box in Delphi to select the date range eventually...

Comment: What this question has to do with [delphi]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add these to the where clause:

```sql
Select Customer.QuoteID, Quote.QuoteID
From Customer, Quote
Where Customer.QuoteID=Quote.QuoteID
  And Quote.CreationDate > '2013-03-31'
Order By Quote.QuoteID
```

Here it is with standard ANSI join syntax, which is generally preferred and which I find a bit easier to read in this case:

```sql
Select Customer.QuoteID, Quote.QuoteID
From Customer
Inner Join Quote On Customer.QuoteID = Quote.QuoteID
Where Quote.CreationDate > '2013-03-31'
Order By Quote.QuoteID
```

Or if you're looking for a range between two dates:

```sql
Select Customer.QuoteID, Quote.QuoteID
From Customer
Inner Join Quote On Customer.QuoteID = Quote.QuoteID
Where Quote.CreationDate >= '2013-03-31' 
  AND Quote.CreationDate <= '2013-04-02'
Order By Quote.QuoteID
```

Finally, on certain RDBMS platforms, you can use the [`BETWEEN` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) as well, but the syntax in my last example will always work.

Comment: Thankyou that's really helpful. I would of never guessed that date format!

Comment: That's the [ISO Date Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Depending on your RDBMS, there may be others supported as well, but that should be fairly universal.

Comment: @AdamTucker If you used parameters in query, the format doesn't matter (assuming from the tag you're using Delphi). You can use native datatypes with most database components sets.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, I was using 28/03/2013 style date format and it didnt like it at all.

Answer (score 6):

To limit by date range you could do something like the following:

```sql
Select Customer.QuoteID, Quote.QuoteID 
From Customer, Quote 
Where Customer.QuoteID = Quote.QuoteID 
  and Quote.CreationDate between :date_from and :date_to
Order By Quote.QuoteID
```

where `:date_from` and `:date_to` are your date parameters